Indicator if a rejected_time within a group is within 5 minutes after a creation_timestamp
I'm trying to set up an indicator for when a new application causes the rejection of an old application.
If any rejected_time within a personal_id occurs within 5 minutes after a creation_timestamp, it has been rejected because of the new application. Based on this, I should create the column "new_application_causes_rejection" as presented in the example.
There are hundreds of thousands of personal IDs, most with multiple application IDs, and the number of rows within the application IDs varies.



personal_id
application_id
creation_timestamp
approved_amount
rejected_time
new_application_causes_rejection




5a
694f
2023-01-24 13:01:07.939534
8000.0
2023-01-24 13:13:15.499000
0


5a
694f
2023-01-24 13:01:07.939534
8000.0
2023-01-24 14:38:02.359000
1


5a
694f
2023-01-24 13:01:07.939534
8000.0
2023-01-24 14:37:18.616000
1


5a
694f
2023-01-24 13:01:07.939534
NaN
2023-01-24 13:03:59.626000
0


5a
43fa
2023-01-24 14:36:08.287521
NaN
2023-01-24 14:37:22.096000
0


5a
43fa
2023-01-24 14:36:08.287521
13000.0
2023-01-24 14:39:31.750000
1


5a
43fa
2023-01-24 14:36:08.287521
13000.0
2023-02-02 08:42:26.980106
1


5a
43fa
2023-01-24 14:36:08.287521
NaN
2023-01-24 14:37:22.948214
0


5a
a4b6
2023-01-24 14:38:42.625969
5000.0
2023-02-02 08:42:26.980106
0


5a
a4b7
2023-01-24 14:38:42.625969
NaN
2023-01-24 14:38:46.922000
0


5a
a4b8
2023-01-24 14:38:42.625969
8000.0
2023-02-02 08:42:26.980106
0




Not sure if understand, why first is 0 and second 1 in new_application_causes_rejection ? Difference of first is 12 Minutes, second 96 Minutes.

The creation_timestamp for the next application_id (43fa) is 2023-01-24 14:36:08.287521. This is later than the rejected_time for the first row 2023-01-24 13:13:15.499000. Hence the rejection of the first row cannot be because of the new application.

The second row is rejected 2023-01-24 14:38:02.359000 and it is less than 5 minutes after the creation_timestamp of the next application (43fa), which is 2023-01-24 14:36:08.287521

I got difference in 6 and 9. rows, is possible check it?

Yes, it works! Great! Many thanks. I'm sorry for the difference in those rows; that was my fault. When I did the example, I cut a lot of rows to make it more manageable in size, and by mistake, I cut some necessary "future" rows.

You can compare shifted values per personal_id and application_id with rejected_time if between 0 and 5 Minutes:
df['creation_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creation_timestamp'])
df['rejected_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['rejected_time'])

#for correct output are columns sorted 
df.sort_values(by=['personal_id', 'creation_timestamp'], inplace=True)


td = pd.Timedelta('5 Min')

#create shifted timestamps per groups
s = (df[['personal_id','application_id','creation_timestamp']]
         .drop_duplicates()
         .set_index(['personal_id','application_id'])['creation_timestamp'].shift(-1))

#subtract shifted values and compare
df['new'] = (df['rejected_time'].sub(df.join(s.rename('new'),
                                             on=['personal_id','application_id'])['new'])
                                .between(pd.Timedelta(0), td).astype(int))


print (df)
   personal_id application_id         creation_timestamp approved_amount  \
0          5a           694f  2023-01-24 13:01:07.939534         8000.0    
1          5a           694f  2023-01-24 13:01:07.939534         8000.0    
2          5a           694f  2023-01-24 13:01:07.939534         8000.0    
3          5a           694f  2023-01-24 13:01:07.939534            NaN    
4          5a           43fa  2023-01-24 14:36:08.287521            NaN    
5          5a           43fa  2023-01-24 14:36:08.287521        13000.0    
6          5a           43fa  2023-01-24 14:36:08.287521        13000.0    
7          5a           43fa  2023-01-24 14:36:08.287521            NaN    
8          5a           a4b6  2023-01-24 14:38:42.625969         5000.0    
9          5a           a4b7  2023-01-24 14:38:42.625969            NaN    
10         5a           a4b8  2023-01-24 14:38:42.625969         8000.0    

                rejected_time  new_application_causes_rejection  new  
0  2023-01-24 13:13:15.499000                                 0    0  
1  2023-01-24 14:38:02.359000                                 1    1  
2  2023-01-24 14:37:18.616000                                 1    1  
3  2023-01-24 13:03:59.626000                                 0    0  
4  2023-01-24 14:37:22.096000                                 0    0  
5  2023-01-24 14:39:31.750000                                 1    1  
6  2023-02-02 08:42:26.980106                                 1    0  
7  2023-01-24 14:37:22.948214                                 0    0  
8  2023-02-02 08:42:26.980106                                 0    0  
9  2023-01-24 14:38:46.922000                                 0    1  
10 2023-02-02 08:42:26.980106                                 0    0  


In case anyone else has the same issue. I needed to sort values before running s to produce the correct output:
df.sort_values(by=['personal_id', 'creation_timestamp'], inplace=True)
